# special character like è,á are not converting their respective unicodes in Ios for other platform like android and app website

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

**I am trying this.**

```
-(NSString *)convertEmojiIntoUnicode:(NSString *)emojiStr{
    NSData *data = [emojiStr dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return goodValue;
}
```

For Decoding

```
-(NSString *)convertUnicodeToEmoji:(NSString *)unicodeStr{
    NSString *newString = unicodeStr;
    NSData *data1 = [newString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *goodValue1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    return goodValue1;
}
```

for characters like è is converting to \350 with above method but I am getting unicode for è- \u00E8 from android and website.

I can decode  \350 and \u00E8 both with above decode method(convertUnicodeToEmoji) to è

Comment: Your code is a bit weird, you convert your string to `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` data then tell `NSString` to convert the data back to a string but tell the constructor that the data is `NSUTF8StringEncoding` and not `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`.

Comment: sir it is working fine for all other emojis and special character except character like È,è

Comment: if è unicode is not right \350 then what is your actual result required ?

Comment: è unicode \\u00E8

Comment: try to print in array.. it will give \\u00E8... `NSMutableArray *arrStr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrStr addObject:@"è"];
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", arrStr);`

Answer (score 0):

Simply try out this solution :

```
 NSString *myString = @"Here is conversion of char ë, é";
    NSData *mData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", strResult);
```

Here is Output :

> Result: Here is conversion of char e, e

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: but with "NSASCIIStringEncoding" emojis are not supporting